# How to hide data passed from Rails view to javascript/coffee?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, coffeescript

I'm trying to pass data from controller to my javascript (.coffee file), and I have found a couple different ways to do that, such as using the data attribute in html like so `<%= content_tag "div", id:"answers", data-answer='<%=@answer%>'` and I have tried the`gon` gem, but the thing is, the data shows up in the html and I want to hide that data from the html because I'm making a quiz app and the users are not suppose to see the answers easily in the html, although I don't mind it inside the .coffee file. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are ways of doing what you describe. First, however, I would write this:

```
<%= content_tag "div", id:"answers", data-answer='<%=@answer%>'
```

like this:

```
<%= content_tag :div, id: "answers", data: {answer: @answer} %>
```

Then, in your `.coffee` file, you could do something along the lines of

```
@$answer = $('#answer').data().answer
$('#answer').remove
```

This will assign the `answer` value to the variable `@$answer` and then remove the original `div` from the `DOM` so the user can't see it.

Comment: Nice work-around, didn't know there is a remove() function. I should've thought of that, thanks

Comment: I changed `data().answer` to `data('answer')` because it says `Cannot read property 'answer'`, but then it says `undefined` in the console. Any idea why?? But the div shows up in the DOM so thats fine, i just need to extract it.

Comment: Fixed it, I need to put it `do` and `end` like so `<%= content_tag :div, id: "answers", data: {answer: @answer} do %>
<% end %>`